# How to create moving particles animation easily with jquery or css

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I have a banner where i have particles moving horizontally with jquery.bgscroll.js with the following code.

```
(function() {
jQuery.fn.bgscroll = jQuery.fn.bgScroll = function( options ) {

    if( !this.length ) return this;
    if( !options ) options = {};
    if( !window.scrollElements ) window.scrollElements = {};

    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {

        var allowedChars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        var randomId = '';
        for( var l = 0; l < 5; l++ ) randomId += allowedChars.charAt( Math.floor( Math.random() * allowedChars.length ) );

            this[ i ].current = 0;
            this[ i ].scrollSpeed = options.scrollSpeed ? options.scrollSpeed : 70;
            this[ i ].direction = options.direction ? options.direction : 'h';
            window.scrollElements[ randomId ] = this[ i ];

            eval( 'window[randomId]=function(){var axis=0;var e=window.scrollElements.' + randomId + ';e.current -= 1;if (e.direction == "h") axis = e.current + "px 0";else if (e.direction == "v") axis = "0 " + e.current + "px";else if (e.direction == "d") axis = e.current + "px " + e.current + "px";jQuery( e ).css("background-position", axis);}' );

            setInterval( 'window.' + randomId + '()', options.scrollSpeed ? options.scrollSpeed : 70 );
        }

        return this;
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

Usage: jQuery('.particles').bgscroll({scrollSpeed:90 , direction:'h'});

It is what i need but after some time like 15mins my page being crashed, dumped because of this.

Is there any easy way to create this same moving animation without page crashing result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Crashing is caused by a recursion, generally. Try replace

```
jQuery.fn.bgscroll = jQuery.fn.bgScroll = function( options )
```

to

```
jQuery.fn.bgScroll = function( options )
```

Comment: It stopped working @Inpyo Jeon. And now am getting this error jQuery(...).bgscroll is not a function.

Comment: @Anahit DEV Try replace (function() --> (function($). If it doesn't work, please post the whole code.

Comment: No it did not solve the issue. You have all the code pasted in my question @Inpyo Jeon